# How to export Facebook Pixel event data

Tags: facebook-pixel

I have a number of events (e.g. ViewContent, AddToCart) being tracked successfully using Facebook pixel. Whilst I can view the recent events in Facebook Business Manager in a graph, and see the last 6 actions in detail, I cannot see a way of exporting the data out of Facebook for further analysis. My events have attached meta data (e.g. what specific product and variant was a user looking at) - and it would be useful for me to look at a history of this data.

Note - these events are not connected to Facebook Ads, just events from the use of the website, so none of the reporting or export options in the Ads Manager show these event details.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: *exporting the data out of Facebook for further analysis* This needs clarification. Currently it's not even clear if this is a programming question.